# C# - Trying to check if value exists in Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

I am creating a program that I will allow you to enter in a number and it will display the information in the respective row. However, if the number is not found in the `num` field, I want it to return with showing the text I set for a label (`label12`). However, I am getting returned with exception errors and I cannot figure out how to create this where if the `num` doesn't exist it will perform a set action.

```cs
olcn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\testlist.mdb");
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from testlist where num = '"+textBox11.Text+"'", olcn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
oda.Fill(dt);
if (oda.Fill(dt).Equals(null))
{
    label12.Show();
}
else if (!oda.Fill(dt).Equals(textBox11.Text))
{
    textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
    textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
    textBox3.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
    textBox4.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
    textBox5.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
    textBox6.Text = dt.Rows[0][6].ToString();
    textBox7.Text = dt.Rows[0][7].ToString();
    textBox8.Text = dt.Rows[0][8].ToString();
    textBox9.Text = dt.Rows[0][9].ToString();
    textBox10.Text = dt.Rows[0][10].ToString();
    bool v = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[0][11].ToString());
    if (!v)
    {
        pictureBox1.Load(dt.Rows[0][11].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        pictureBox1.Load(dt.Rows[0][12].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The question should be updated to include the error

Comment: `OleDbDataAdapter.Fill()` returns [an `int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-data-common-dbdataadapter-fill(system-data-datatable)). You are trying to compare it to `null` via `Equals()`, and to a `string`, also via `Equals()`.

Comment: As @GSerg mentioned, the `Fill` method returns int32 according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill?view=net-7.0). You cannot compare integers with null using the `Equal` method. 
see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

The result of the `Fill()` method is the number of rows returned. Just update your code to check the result of `Fill()` is greater than zero records.

```
olcn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\testlist.mdb");
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from testlist where num = '"+textBox11.Text+"'", olcn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
int count = oda.Fill(dt);
if (count == 0)
{
    label12.Show();
}
else
{
    // ... your mapping logic
}
```

MS Documentation, [OleDbDataAdapter.Fill Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.fill?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-data-oledb-oledbdataadapter-fill(system-data-datatable-system-object))